# Difficulty adding a parent menu link

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm creating a custom module in Drupal 8.4.4. I put several menu links under the `Development` menu.

```
scrape.scrape_form:
  title: 'Scrape'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: scrape.scrape_form
  description: 'Scrape content from ccad.edu'
  weight: 10

scrape.scrape_images_form:
  title: 'Images Scrape'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: scrape.scrape_images_form
  description: 'Scrape images from ccad.edu'
  weight: 20

...
```

This is working fine, but now that whole menu is getting a bit too long.

I wanted to wrap up all of my links under one 'header' link under the `Development` menu.  I added this at the top of `mymodule.links.menu.yml`:

```
scrape.migration:
  title: 'Migration'
  description: 'Migration functions'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route:<nolink>
  menu_name: scrape.migration
  route_name: scrape.migration
```

But when I try to rebuild the cache, I get this error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route &quot;scrape.migration&quot; does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()
```

How can I make a new, non-navigable parent link under `Development`, to put my custom links under?

**Edit** 4k4's comment is correct, but my parent link is very small and greyed out.

```
scrape.migration:
  title: 'Migration'
  description: 'Migration functions'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  menu_name: scrape.migration
  route_name: <nolink>
```

[image]

How can I get a full-height, dark-font header link?

Comment: shouldn't this be `route_name: <nolink>`?

Comment: @4k4 your comment fixed my error and gave me the link, but there is a further wrinkle. Please see edit. Thank you!

Comment: looks like you do not have a CSS style for a menu item that do not include the markup for a link.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `route_name: <nolink>`, I suggest providing a route for the link and e.g. pointing that route to Drupal's default overview page contoller. This should fix your issue and assures the users can click the menu link and get an overview of the available functions (e.g. when re-using your module in a Drupal that has no Admin Toolbar installed):

**mymodule.links.menu.yml**

```
scrape.migration:
  title: 'Migration'
  description: 'Migration functions'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: scrape.migration
```

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
scrape.migration:
  path: '/admin/config/development/scrape'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::overview'
    link_id: 'scrape.migration'
    _title: 'Migration'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
```

You might have to adapt the path/permissions accordingly.

Comment: I have a page, but when I navigate to it, I get "You do not have any administrative items. "

Comment: Did you set the parent of your submenu items correctly? They need to be the item using the overview controller.

Comment: This is what I have in my `module.links.menu.yml`: `scrape.migration:
  title: 'Migration'
  description: 'Migration functions'
  parent: system.admin_config_development
  route_name: scrape.migration
  weight: 10

scrape.scrape_form:
  title: 'Scrape Static Pages'
  parent: scrape.migration
  route_name: scrape.scrape_form
  description: 'Scrape static content'
  weight: 20`

Answer (score 1):

Just thought it would be easier to show a basic example that has both parent and submenu item in the mymodule.links.menu.yml.

Right now both links goto the same place (as I had to pick a default for the parent item, since I didn't have a admin page that lists all my custom links yet ... and also since having "route_name: <nolink>" did not work for the parent menu item even though some peeps said it worked for them [Note: using Drupal 8.6.12]):

```
mymodule.parent:
  title: 'My MainMenu Link'
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'Custom main config menu item under the Admin->Configuration menu.'
  route_name: mymodule.form
  weight: 100

mymodule.parent_child:
  title: 'My Submenu Link'
  parent: mymodule.parent
  description: 'This is the sub-menu item for my custom config form.'
  route_name: mymodule.form
  weight: 101
```